# I wish to update an empty field using data from another table

Tags: mysql-error-1064, sql-update

I used the SELECT COUNT(*) to check my WHERE statement and got the correct number of updates, however when I attempt the UPDATE I get a syntax error around line 3.

```
UPDATE scans AS s
SET s.sbjnum = d.sbjnum
JOIN details AS d on d.name = s.name
WHERE s.sbjnum =''
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to have a `FROM` to have a `JOIN`

```
UPDATE scans 
SET sbjnum = d.sbjnum 
FROM scans s
JOIN details AS d ON d.name = s.name 
WHERE s.sbjnum =''
```

According to the MySQL manual you can write it like this:

```
UPDATE scans AS s
JOIN details AS d ON d.name = s.name 
SET sbjnum = d.sbjnum 
WHERE s.sbjnum =''
```